# override variable imported from module in python

Tags: python, overriding

a.py:

```
import sys

h = 'this is h from a.py'

for i in sys.argv:
    if i in ['-h']:
        print(h)
```

b.py:

```
import sys
from a import h


h='this is h from b.py'
for i in sys.argv:
    if i in ['-h']:
        print(h)
```

Then I get:

```
>$  python b.py -h
 this is h from a.py
 this is h from b.py
```

Shouldn't **'h'** have been overridden? Or is a.py accessing the **'-h'** argument given to b.py?

Thank you

Comment: Put `from a import h` below `h=....`. The way you have it written, you are overwriting `h` from `a.py`

Comment: It was overridden; but the code in `a.py` all executes before the equivalent loop in `b.py`.

Comment: And note that you aren't overriding `a.h`; you are simply initializing `b.h` with the value of `a.h`, then immediately assigning a new value to `b.h`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import a, all the code inside a.py is executed, thence you will always have the printed output:

> > this is h from a.py

To avoid it, you can change a.py to:

```
import sys

h = 'this is h from a.py'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in sys.argv:
        if i in ['-h']:
            print(h)
```

This way, the code inside the if clause will only be executed when you call `python a.py -h`, and not when you call `python b.py -h`.

Comment: My learnt lesson is that it's dangerous to use `from fileX import *` when you have global variables in _fileX_

Answer (score 2):

## The main question

You can overwrite the variable from `b.py` with the following code:

```
import a
a.h = 'actually replaced value'
```

Note: actually adding that to `a.py` will still give the following result:

```
>$  python b.py -h
 this is h from a.py
 this is h from b.py
```

## Creating the wanted behavior

First note that you can verify that the value of h gets changed with the following code:

a.py:

```
import sys

h = 'this is h from a.py'

for i in sys.argv:
    if i in ['-h']:
        print(h)


def what_is_h():
    print('h:', h)
```

b.py:

```
import sys
from a import h, what_is_h
import a

what_is_h()
a.h = h = 'this is h from b.py'
what_is_h()

for i in sys.argv:
    if i in ['-h']:
        print(h)
```

This results in the following:

```
this is h from a.py
h: this is h from a.py
h: this is h from b.py
this is h from b.py
```

The first `what_is_h` call shows the original `h` value and the second shows the modified value. The problem is `a.py` and `b.py` seem to have different versions of the variable `h` this is what is called scope. When you use the `import` statement python parses your file and runs the code. The way you can prevent this automatic running of the code is by placing it in a function, importing it and running it from `b.py` preferably passing `h` as an argument (since global state is usually bad practice in python).

### *"What if I want to run a function from `a.py` too but only if I run it directly?"*

Now if you want a function executed when you run `a.py` or `b.py` but run the function in `a.py` only if it is run directly you can add the following to the bottom of your script file:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_function()
```

This will run the function `my_function` only when you execute `$> python a.py`.
Note that when importing `a.py` it will not run `my_function` unless run otherwise.

How does this work?
`__name__` is a built-in global variable that stores the "name" the python interpreter gives to python scripts. The file that is run is given the `__name__` `'__main__'`. Now when importing something from `a.py` `__name__` will equal `'a'` and `my_function` will not run.

## Further style notes and tips for your code

- equality:

instead of

```
if i in ['-h']:
  # ... your code
```

do

```
if i == '-h':
  # ... your code
```

if you want to check for multiple flags later you can change it.

- checking if something is in a list or sequence-like object:

if you only want to check if `-h` is in `sys.args` you can do:

```
if '-h' in sys.args:
  # ... your code
```

instead of

```
for i in sys.args:
  if i == '-h':
    # ... your code
```

- parsing, handling and dealing with command line arguments

If you plan to do more complex things with arguments there is library that should be included by default with every installation of python, namely the [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) library.

I hope I was able to help.

Comment: I appreciate your effort. I believe that either I did not express myself correctly or you did not understand my question. I will close this question and will ask it again trying to be more clear. BTW: No need for extras (e.g. styles...).